# Passing memoryview to C function

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have a C function declared as follows:

```
void getIndexOfState(long *p, long C, long G, long B, long *state);
```

Nowadays my cython wrapper code uses the buffer syntax from numpy array:

```
cpdef int getIndexOfState(self, np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1, mode="c"] s):
    cdef long out
    getIndexOfState(&out, self.C, self.G, self.B, <long*> s.data)
    return out
```

I want to use the new memoryview syntax, my question is, how can I pass the pointer to the data when using a memoryview?

I tried:

```
cpdef int getIndexOfState(self, long[:] s):
    cdef long out
    getIndexOfState(&out, self.C, self.G, self.B, s)
    return out
```

which raised the "Cannot assign type 'long[:]' to 'long *'" error when I was trying to compile the module. There is any way to pass that pointer without coercing the memoryview back to a numpy array before calling the C function?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the underlying data is [properly contiguous/strided](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#specifying-more-general-memory-layouts) and there is at least one element in the memory, then it should suffice to pass a pointer to the first element (and maybe the length):

```
getIndexOfState(&out, self.C, self.G, self.B, &s[0])
```

EDIT:

One way to ensure "properly contiguous" should be the addition of "[::1]".

```
cpdef int getIndexOfState(self, long[::1] s):
    cdef long out
    getIndexOfState(&out, self.C, self.G, self.B, &s[0])
    return out
```