# np.ascontiguousarray versus np.asarray with Cython

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy, cython

follow up question to [how to pass numpy array to Cython function correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055196/how-to-pass-numpy-array-to-cython-function-correctly):

when passing numpy.ndarrays in Cython to a C function that only deals with contiguous arrays, is there a difference between doing:

```
np.ndarray[double, ndim=1, mode="c"] arr = np.ascontiguousarray(np.array([1,2,3],dtype=float))
```

and

```
np.ndarray[double, ndim=1, mode="c"] arr = np.asarray(np.array([1,2,3],dtype=float), order="c")
```

are both necessary? Does `np.ascontiguous` implies already that the array will be in a format that can be assigned to an array with a `mode=c` declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just do:

```
np.ndarray[double, ndim=1, mode="c"] arr = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.float64, order="c")
```

From the docs for `np.array`:

```
order : {'C', 'F', 'A'}, optional
    Specify the order of the array.  If order is 'C' (default), then the
    array will be in C-contiguous order (last-index varies the
    fastest).  If order is 'F', then the returned array
    will be in Fortran-contiguous order (first-index varies the
    fastest).  If order is 'A', then the returned array may
    be in any order (either C-, Fortran-contiguous, or even
    discontiguous).
```

My understanding is that you only need to use `np.ascontiguousarray` if the array you are trying to pass was generated from some non-contiguous slice of another array. If you are creating the array from scratch, it shouldn't be necessary.

For example:

```
a = np.arange(10)
a.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS'] # True
b = a[::2]
b.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS'] # False

c = np.ascontiguousarray(b)
c.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS'] # True
```

Also, perhaps consider using the [typed memoryview](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) interface

```
double[::1] arr = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.float64)
```

Answer (score 8):

The [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html) for `ascontiguousarray` states that it will return a C ordered array, so yes, if you use `ascontiguousarray` you can then assume the data is ordered in `c` mode.

To then answer what differences are there between the two, we can read the source.

`asarray` ([link](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L392)) does this:

```
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
```

`ascontiguousarray` ([link](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L514)) does this:

```
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order='C', ndmin=1)
```

so when you call asarray with `order='C'`, the only difference with `ascontiguousarray` is that you choose the default value for ndmin, which is `0`. This boils down to this difference, when you use the two methods on a single number instead of a list:

```
print asarray(4,dtype='float',order='c').shape
()
print ascontiguousarray(4,dtype='float').shape
(1,)
```

It's up to you, but I prefer `ascontiguousarray`, as I often rely on the possibility of processing the shape attribute of the array, and expect it to be non-empty. In a sense, it's like calling `atleast1d` as well at the same time.