# Passing multidimensional memoryviews to c-function

Tags: multidimensional-array, cython, typed

The answers in the following thread did not help mee since I have multidimensional arrays [Passing memoryview to C function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584439/passing-memoryview-to-c-function).

I have the following test code:

Header file:

```
//cm.h
double per(double **marr,int rows,int cols);
```

File with C-function

```
//cm.c
#include <stdio.h>
double per(double **marr,int rows,int cols){
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for (j=0;j<cols;j++){
            //Just update the array
            marr[i][j] = (double)(i+1)*(j+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Cython file:

```
#m.pyz
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from cython.view cimport array as cvarray

cdef extern from 'cm.h':
    double per(double **marr,int rows,int cols);

def test(double[:,::1] x):
    cdef int rows = x.shape[0]
    cdef int cols = x.shape[1]
    per(x,rows,cols)
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            print x[i,j]
```

And error message:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    double per(double **marr,int rows,int cols);

def test(double[:,::1] x):
    cdef int rows = x.shape[0]
    cdef int cols = x.shape[1]
    per(x,rows,cols)
        ^
------------------------------------------------------------

m.pyx:12:9: Cannot assign type 'double[:, ::1]' to 'double **'
```

I have read that typed memoryviews is the most modern way of handling Python arrays in Cython, but I cannot find out how to do this. I have some numerical recipes in C which operates on dynamicall made large multidimensional arrays. 
Is what I try to do a totally wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally the memoryview is actually stored as a 1D array together with some information about the sizes of the dimensions. See http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#brief-recap-on-c-fortran-and-strided-memory-layouts

(As a slight side note you can have memoryviews with "indirect" dimensions which do store things as pointer to pointers. This only makes sense if they're a view of something that already has memory allocated like that - for example if you build a 2D array like that in C. You won't get those from (say) numpy objects so I'll ignore this detail).

You change the C to be

```
// pass a 1D array, and then calculate where we should be looking in it
// based on the stride
double per(double *marr,int rows,int cols, int row_stride, int col_stride){
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for (j=0;j<cols;j++){
            //Just update the array
            marr[row_stride*i + col_stride*j] = (double)(i+1)(j+1);
        }
    }
}
```

The Cython code then needs changes to pass it the strides (which is stored in bytes, so divide by the itemsize to get the strides in "number of doubles" which C expects), together with the address of the first element

```
// also update the cdef defintion for per...
per(&x[0,0],x.shape[0],x.shape[1],
     x.strides[0]/x.itemsize,x.strides[1]/x.itemsize)
```

Comment: Do I need to use the strides? Wil it not be correct to use pointer artmetic like this: marr[i*row +j] in order to acess the element. This works find in pure c when make a 2 dimensional array like with double *marr = malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(double)

Comment: Maybe. Strides works generally. You can take slices of numpy arrays (e.g. `array[2:5,3:10]`) and in that case the strides won't equal the number of columns. By specifying your arrayview as `[:,::1]` you've ensured that `col_stride=1`, but I don't think you've ensured that `row_stride=cols`. I decided to give you the solution that always works and avoid having to think about this!

Comment: When row_strides != cols is it because the array is not contiguous in memory i.e. there are "something" between each row?

Comment: Another thing. For a numpy array the colum stride = 8 bytes. Using this in C do not get the correct results.

Comment: 1) Yes, in principle there can be something between each row. It's often the end of the row that you're choosing not to look at. 2) Is my mistake - sorry! Strides is apparently always given in bytes, so you need to divide by itemsize. I'll edit my answer to fix that...

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Everything working now:)