# The simplest way to pass pointer to contiguous data from Python to C

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am using `ctypes` to call function in `C`.  Function expects pointer to the first element of the contiguous data and number of data.

One thing that works is something like that

```
a=15 # a could be any number
temp = numpy.array([a]*14, dtype=numpy.int8)
c_function(temp.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p), 14)
```

This is really cumbersome, requires both `numpy` and `ctypes`.  Is there any other more simple way that works both in Python2 and Python3 (AFAIK `bytes([a]*14)` works but only for Python3)

EDIT: More interestingly this also works (!)

```
a=15 # a could be any number
temp = chr(a)*14
c_function(temp, 14)
```

There were suggestions in other threads that one could pass something pointer to the first element of the contiguous data, like here [Passing memoryview to C function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584439/passing-memoryview-to-c-function), but I was just unable to make this work.

Comment: It's important to understand that in one very real sense, you cannot ever pass a pointer from Python to C, because *Python does not have pointers*.  What you can do is pass a Python object that somehow represents a pointer, by some mechanism, specific to the chosen Python representation, that instructs the C side to interpret the object as a pointer.  The three essential elements are (i) represent a pointer as a Python object (*e.g.* via numpy); (ii) pass it (via Python); (iii) using an appropriate mechanism (*e.g.* ctypes). ...

Comment: There are no doubt *other* ways to do it than numpy -> Python -> ctypes, but they all must have analogues of those three components.  I think the best you can hope for is an approach in which components (i) and (iii) are the same, so I guess ctypes -> Python -> ctypes if you're locked into ctypes for (iii).  Can't you just use ctypes to wrap a call to `malloc()`?

Comment: Why not homogenize (backport actually) the behavior of `bytes` between python versions, doing `from builtins import bytes` ?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was hoping for the solution that includes only standard Python libraries.  Both `ctypes` and `numpy` are indeed used by `Python` chip library that calls the `C` code.  I would like that the user of the library does not have to import either `ctypes` or `numpy` and that the solution is as user friendly as possible.

Comment: @Pygmalion, leaving aside the pointers for a moment, to the best of knowledge, Python has no built-in mechanism for calling *any* C function, unless you count its C-language API.  The cleanest thing to do from a user perspective would probably be to use that to write an extension module in C, in which you can do all the C-ish things you like.  Otherwise, you need ctypes, and / or Cython, and / or some similar third party package to do C-ish things for you.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Let me rephrase my question.  I can create contiguous array of bytes using `bytearray([a]*14)`.  All I actually need is to find a "pointer" to array.  My guess was to use `memoryview`, but it did not help.  Neither did `&a[0]`.  It seems if I just miss a small detail.

Comment: @JohnBollinger What really surprises me that if you define string `x="abc"`, `x` is actually a pointer you can send to `C`.  This is also true for `x=b"abc"`.  So one solution could be to create bytes from list, but this does not seem to work in Python2.

Comment: @Pygmalion, no, in Python, `x="abc"` *does not* produce `x` as a pointer (directly) to the memory containing 'a', 'b', 'c', not even if you look at it in terms of cpython's C implementation.  Going back and forth between the Python object wrapping the data and a C pointer directly to the data is among the things that `ctypes` is doing for you in your present solution.  Python does not offer a built-in way to do the same, in part because, as I said at the beginning, Python does not have pointers.  Python's is a higher-level view of the world than C's is.

Comment: cpython's C implementation does use pointers to objects, and its C API provides a mechanism for native extensions to access those pointers, but those are not the pointers you want.  They point to object metadata, such as type information and reference counts.  If you allow your C function to clobber that then you will cause yourself a lot of grief.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well, if I create a string `a = "abc"` and pass `a` to `C` code where it expects pointer, it works!  Perhaps `ctypes` converts `a` to `c_void_p`... no idea, I just know for sure it works.

Comment: @Pygmalion, yes, ctypes automatically performs certain argument conversions.  Your question has become clear to me now, and I will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

### Preliminaries

Python does not have pointers.  You cannot create a pointer in Python, though Python variables act in some ways like pointers.  You can create Python objects that *represent* lower-level pointers, but what you actually seem to want is to feed your C function a pointer to Python-managed data, which is an altogether different thing.

### What ctypes does for you

You seem to have settled on using ctypes for the actual function call, so the general question expressed in the question title is a little overbroad for what you actually want to know.  The real question seems to be more like "How do I get ctypes to pass a C pointer to Python-managed data to a C function?"

According to the [ctypes Python 2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ctypes.html), in Python 2,

> `None`, integers, longs, byte strings and unicode strings are the only
> native Python objects that can directly be used as parameters in these
> function calls. `None` is passed as a C NULL pointer, **byte strings and
> unicode strings are passed as pointer to the memory block that
> contains their data** (`char *` or `wchar_t *`). [...]

(emphasis added).

It's more or less the same list [in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ctypes.html) ...

> `None`, integers, bytes objects and (unicode) strings

... with the same semantics.

Note well that ctypes takes care of the conversion from Python object to corresponding C representation -- nowhere does Python code handle C pointers *per se*, nor even direct representations of them.

### Relevant C details

In many C implementations, all object pointer types have the same representation and can be used semi-interchangeably, but pointers of type `char *` are *guaranteed by the standard* to have the same size and representation as pointers of type `void *`.  These two pointer types are guranteed to be interchangeable as function parameters and return values, among other things.

### Synthesis

How convenient! It is acceptable to call your C function with a first argument of type `char *` when the function declares that parameter to be of type `void *`, and that is exactly what ctypes will arrange for you when the Python argument is a byte string (Python 2) or a bytes object (Python 3).  The C function will receive a pointer to the object's data, not to the object itself.  This provides a simpler and better way forward than going through numpy or a similar package, and it is basically the approach that you appended to your question.  Thus, supposing that `c_function` identifies a ctypes-wrapped C function, you could do this (python3):

```
len = 15
c_function(b'0' * len, len)
```

Of course, you can also create a variable for the object and pass that, instead, which would allow you to afterward see whatever the C function has done with the contents of the object.

Do note, however, that

1. Byte strings and bytes objects are immutable as far as Python is concerned.  You can get yourself in trouble if you use a C function to change the contents of a bytes object that other Python code assumes will never change.
2. The C side cannot determine the size of the data from a pointer to it.  That is presumably the purpose of the second parameter.  If you tell the function that the object is larger than it really is, and the function relies on that to try to modify bytes past the end of the actual data, then you will have difficult to debug trouble, from corruption of other data to memory leaks.  If you're lucky, your program will crash.
3. It depends on what Python implementation you use, but typically the elements of a Unicode string are larger than one byte each.  Save yourself some trouble and use byte strings / bytes instead.

Comment: FYI, `str` (Unicode strings) are converted to `wchar_t*` encoded in UTF-16..convenient for wide Windows APIs.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, I know that Unicode strings are presented on the C side as `wchar_t *`, but those are documented to point to the strings' internal data, which is not necessarily encoded in UTF-16.  In CPython it may be UCS4, for example.  Perhaps that's unusual when CPython is built for Windows, though.

Comment: point to the docs.  Python 3 uses latin1, UCS-2, or UCS-4 to store Unicode strings based on the content, but `ctypes` converts them to UTF-16 (surrogates and all) for `ctypes.c_wchar_p` on Windows, and likely UTF-32 on Linux, depending on `wchar_t` definition.  Python 3 doesn't use surrogates internally.  `ctypes` marshals to a correct `wchar_t*`.  Test yourself with `ctypes.create_unicode_buffer('\U0001F5AC')`.  It returns a 3-element array (two surrogates and null termination).

Comment: @MarkTolonen, I'm looking at https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html, which says, in part, "bytes objects and strings are passed as pointer to the memory block that contains their data". That's subject to interpretation, I suppose, but I take the use of the definite article (*the* memory block) to indicate that no copying or transcoding is performed, as indeed seems most natural.  Nor do those docs anywhere mention transcoding in general or UTF-16 in particular.  That doesn't necessarily mean you're wrong, but I'd love to see some documentation supporting your claim.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, note also that C does not specify that `wchar_t` is 16 bits in size.  That often *is* its size, but it is permitted to be either narrower or wider, as the C implementation chooses, and the type has no particular association with any specific encoding.

Comment: Yes, there are Python C APIs to return a `PyUnicode` as a particular C representation, so I suspect `ctypes` as built for Windows is using them to get UTF-16, as needed by `wchar_t*`.  Linux versions would of course be different.  The documentation is thin, and I haven't source-dived, but it **is** the behavior seen.  I **have** implemented SWIG templates using those same APIs.  Python 3 uses a variable memory block based on the content of Unicode strings, and it is definitely not variable when it gets to a C function taking a `wchar_t*`.

Comment: Not that you seem in any way uncertain, @MarkTolonen, but [the code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/db68544122f5a0c7b80f69c0e643049efa6699c6/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c#L718) does appear to say you're right.